# Why was this question about continued fraction expansion of a rational function closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I mean the question [Continued fraction expansion of a rational function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170931/35000) asked more than two years ago and closed about three months ago as off-topic.

Why is it off-topic? Presently I actually need something like that, and I think Mathematica is well-suited for such kind of symbolic calculations. I believe it would be very nice if some expert would have look at it: maybe a clever combination of `ContinuedFraction`, `ContinuedFractionK`, `PolynomialRemainder`, `PolynomialExtendedGCD`, `SolveAlways` and such could produce a nice answer which doubtlessly would be very useful.

There was one answer which contains a promising idea but seems to be flawed.

Does anybody remember what was the reason behind closing it?

Comment: Looking at the [revision history](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/170931/revisions) originally there was pretty much no info. Then Henrik helpfully added a bunch of background, but people probably still felt there wasn't any proper attempt by the OP to even solve the problem. You can petition to have it reopened if you have an answer or can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Presently I don't see any substantial way to improve it. How can I petition for reopening? I believe I don't have enough reputation for reopening votes

Comment: @b3m2a1, indeed, მამუკა is short of the [3000 rep](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) needed to cast reopen votes.

Comment: If at least two other people vote to reopen, I'll cast my reopen vote AND post the method I was alluding to in the question's comments (Thiele expansion).

Comment: @J.M. I appreciate that. Otherwise, I can launch another question about that.

Comment: It got bumped recently by the Community bot. Someone then saw it as a question that no one could answer. it had been two years after all, and the OP had not responded to a very reasonable request to give an example. Then four other people agreed. Perhaps they had other reasons, but I'd say the apparent lack of interest in the question by the community and by the OP was sufficient justification to close it. OTOH, when someone voted to reopen it, I edited in a code example and voted to reopen, too  The OP is not going to return to accept an answer. Might have been better to ask your own..

Comment: Glad to see it reopened, and a most useful answer promptly added. I believe one of the commenters might post an answer about that here, which I could accept.

Comment: Judging by what @MichaelE2 says there might be a problem with accepting that answer. This last situation (with no OP present to accept the answer), by the way, might be content of another meta question. Or has such situation been already discussed on meta before?